# Translating from English to a proposition using predicate calculus

Tags: predicate-logic

The following sentence needs to be translated from english to a proposition using universal and existential quantifiers.

> Everyone in this class knows exactly one person that goes to university.

I have been using the following predicates:

> let  U = all people
>
> let C(*x*) = *x in this class*
>
> let K(*x*,*y*) = *x knows y*
>
> let N (*y*) = *y goes to university*

My attempt:

> ∀x (C(*x*) ∧ N (*y*) ∧ K(*x*,*y)*
>
> [Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)

I am struggling to denote the **exactly one** portion and keeping the integrity of the sentence.

Comment: Interpret the sentence in the following way: If $x$ is in this class then $x$ knows $y$ and if $x$ also knows $z$ then $y=z$.

Comment: And don't forget to existentially quantify $y$: for every $x$ in the class there exists a $y$ who goes to university.